# SCP from one external server to another

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, bash, scp

I am trying to a SCP on my local server that copies a file from one remote server to another remote server (Both remote servers use a custom port (xxxx)

I am trying:

```
scp -r -P xxxx root@xxx.xxx.xxx.111:/home/myimages/images.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.222:/home/myimages/images.tar.gz
```

But i get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.222 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679534/scp-from-one-external-server-to-another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
ssh -p xxxx root@xxx.xxx.xxx.111 "scp -r -P xxxx /home/myimages/images.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.222:/home/myimages/images.tar.gz"
```

An SSH followed by an SCP.

Comment: I agree, +1 for the solution as it avoids data transferring down from server 1 and up to server 2 (2 transfers instead of 1 as suggested)

Comment: what I was going to write, then forgot about the page :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.111 'tar cf - /home/myimages/images.tar.gz' | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.222 'tar xf -'
```

Ssh-pipes are extremely useful. Learn and love them!